# How to get text from html input field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a pdf report using php.
First, user will need to key in the name in the input box, and the name will be passed to the 2nd php page which will search mysql database.

problem : after user key in the name, i try to call the data (var student_id = $('#nama_student').val()), but the script states it is undefined.

p/s : sorry if code not sanitized, I'm still learning, by myself..

codes:

```
php

//attendance.php

include('header.php');

$student_list_id = '';
$error_student_list_id = '';
$error = 0;
$success = '';

?>

<div class="container" style="margin-top:30px">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9"><b>Attendance List</b></div>
        <div class="col-md-3" align="right">
          <button type="button" id="report_button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Report</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="table-responsive">
        <span id="message_operation"></span>
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="attendance_table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Student Name</th>
              <th>Card No</th>
              <th>Date</th>
              <th>Time In</th>
              <th>Time Out</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>

          </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/datepicker.css" />

<style>
    .datepicker
    {
      z-index: 1600 !important; /* has to be larger than 1050 */
    }
</style>



<div class="modal" id="reportModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <!-- Modal Header -->
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Make Report</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal body -->
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
        <form method="post">
            Name: <input type="text" name="name1"><br>
            <?php $nama_student = $_POST["name1"]; 
            ?>
            </form>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal footer -->
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" name="create_report" id="create_report" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Create Report</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  var dataTable = $('#attendance_table').DataTable({
    "processing":true,
    "serverSide":true,
    "order":[],
    "ajax":{
      url:"attendance_action.php",
      method:"POST",
      data:{action:"fetch"}
    }
  });

  $('#attendance_date').datepicker({
    format:'yyyy-mm-dd',
    autoclose:true,
    container: '#formModal modal-body'
  });

  function clear_field()
  {
    $('#attendance_form')[0].reset();
    $('#error_attendance_date').text('');
  }

  $('#add_button').click(function(){
    $('#modal_title').text("Add Attendance");
    $('#formModal').modal('show');
    clear_field();
  });

  $('#attendance_form').on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url:"attendance_action.php",
      method:"POST",
      data:$(this).serialize(),
      dataType:"json",
      beforeSend:function(){
        $('#button_action').val('Validate...');
        $('#button_action').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      },
      success:function(data)
      {
        $('#button_action').attr('disabled', false);
        $('#button_action').val($('#action').val());
        if(data.success)
        {
          $('#message_operation').html('<div class="alert alert-success">'+data.success+'</div>');
          clear_field();
          $('#formModal').modal('hide');
          dataTable.ajax.reload();
        }
        if(data.error)
        {
          if(data.error_attendance_date != '')
          {
            $('#error_attendance_date').text(data.error_attendance_date);
          }
          else
          {
            $('#error_attendance_date').text('');
          }
        }
      }
    })
  });

  $('.input-daterange').datepicker({
    todayBtn:"linked",
    format:"yyyy-mm-dd",
    autoclose:true,
    container: '#formModal modal-body'
  });

  $(document).on('click', '#report_button', function(){
    $('#reportModal').modal('show');
  });

  $('#create_report').click(function(){

    var student_id = $('#nama_student').val();

    $('#formModal').modal('hide');
    window.open("report.php?action=attendance_report&student_id="+student_id);



  });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Ok, not a PHP question in reality. You need jquery help and you need to edit tags since I can't from this view.

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue in your code here:

```
...
<form method="post">
  Name: <input type="text" name="name1"><br>
  <?php $nama_student = $_POST["name1"]; ?>
</form>
...
```

[jQuery selector](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) will not work like this, [jQuery selector](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) should be used the same way you are using them in CSS, so when you select input by a dynamic id from PHP you should print that name in the `id` attribute like the following:

```
<form method="post">
  Name: <input type="text" name="name1" id="student_name"><br>
  <?php $nama_student = $_POST["name1"];  ?></br>
</form>
```

then in javascript:

```
...
$('#create_report').click(function(){
  var student_id = $('#nama_student').val();
...
```

**Update**: based on @ecarrizo: you can just do PHP echo for the variable value inside your javascript like this:

```
...
$('#create_report').click(function(){
    var student_id = <?php echo $_POST["name1"]; ?>
    $('#formModal').modal('hide');
    window.open("report.php?action=attendance_report&student_id="+student_id);
});
...
```

Comment: i would rather add some unique id to the input identifier and then use it on the place that the OP wants to obtain the value `id="some_unique_id"` then  `var student_id = $('#some_unique_id').val();` or add an example on how to access form variables to solve op problem.

Comment: @ecarrizo, sure thing I will add it to my answer but, the OP, seems to not know  how to use jQuery selector, that's the main issue.

Comment: Yes, in fact the problem is that he is mixing both languages. He is declaring a PHP variable that is not accessible from javascript, and hence he is not creating an element with the id #nama_student, neither assigning any input value to the form name input, so even with your solution the value will still be null.

To fix OP problem you have to: #1: Assign value to input name "name1", #2 Assign unique id to the input element and then access its value.

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues on your script so let start from scratch:

**Issue #1 - You are declaring a PHP Variable but doing nothing with it.**

You are retrieving `name1` POST value in your php script and storing it on the variable `$nama_student` but this variable is not used later in your code.

You might want to print it using the `echo` PHP instruction.

```
// Example 
<?php echo $_POST["name1"]; ?>
```

**Issue #2 - There is not an element with id `#nama_student`**
in your HTML this element do not exists so the element is undefined and you cannot access its value using the jquery instuction `$('#nama_student')`.

Since your intention here is to retrieve the value of the form element `name1` You should assign the identifier that you are proposing to that element, so it is no longer undefined!

```
// Example
<input type="text" name="name1" id="nama_student">
```

**Issue #3 - You are not assigning back the value to the element that you are trying to retrieve the value from**

Even if your intention was to 'echo' the value after the input, that will not assign the value to the input element, then, even if you can access your form element, you are not going to get any value from `val()`.
To solve this you need to assign the value to the input.

```
<input type="text" name="name1" value="you print the php variable here">
```

Now that you understand the problem you are having, try to put it all together:

```
<input type="text" name="name1" id="nama_student" value="<?php echo $_POST["name1"]; ?>">
```

Then your `$('#nama_student').val()`, should have a value